# Navigation Bar not showing Bar Button Items

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Kindly somebody help me.

I have a weird situation where my navigation bar is showing the title but hiding the bar button items. I have a left and a right bar button which are hidden. Please refer to the screenshot and let me know the solution.

Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rm3p.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up the bar button items? Is this in a storyboard or programatic? Need a bit more information / code here to work off of.

Comment: I have added them on storyboard. They are showing up on the scene.